# Plsql For loops and nested If loops

Tags: plsql

Don't know what's s wrong with this plsql statement:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE


CURSOR EMP_UPDATE IS
    SELECT EMP_ID ,NAME ,DESIGNATION ,SALARY ,GRADE  
    FROM EMPLOYEE1;


BEGIN 
        FOR REC IN EMP_UPDATE LOOP
            IF REC.EMP_ID <= MAX(REC.EMP_ID) 
            THEN
            IF REC.NAME IS NOT NULL 
            THEN
            IF REC.SALARY <= 1000 
            THEN
            UPDATE EMPLOYEE1 SET GRADE = 'D' WHERE EMP_ID = REC.EMP_ID;
            ELSE IF REC.SALARY BETWEEN 1001 AND 5000 THEN
            UPDATE EMPLOYEE1 SET GRADE = 'C' WHERE EMP_ID = REC.EMP_ID;
            ELSE IF REC.SALARY BETWEEN 5001 AND 10000 THEN
            UPDATE EMPLOYEE1 SET GRADE = 'B' WHERE EMP_ID = REC.EMP_ID;
            ELSE IF REC.SALARY BETWEEN 10000 AND 20000 THEN
            UPDATE EMPLOYEE1 SET GRADE = 'A' WHERE EMP_ID = REC.EMP_ID;
            ELSE IF REC.SALARY > 20000 THEN
            UPDATE EMPLOYEE1 SET GRADE = 'S' WHERE EMP_ID = REC.EMP_ID;
            ELSE  
            UPDATE EMPLOYEE1 SET REC.NAME = (SELECT NAME FROM EMPL_DATABASE ED WHERE         ED.EMP_ID = REC.EMP_ID) WHERE EMP_ID = REC.EMP_ID;
            END IF;
            END IF;
            END IF;
        END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What should the statement be doing that it isn't? Please edit that into your question.

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Please study the basic syntax first.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the syntax problems:

- Use `ELSIF` instead of `ELSE IF`.
- Get rid of the `MAX(REC.EMP_ID)` line.  You can't perform an aggregation on a cursor like that, it has to be part of the SQL statement.  But you don't need to
  do that anyway.  A cursor-for loop will automatically stop when there are no more rows.

Here is some generic programming advice:

- Style and formatting matter.  They will help you and others understand the code.
- Always start with the smallest possible code and stop when you hit a single error.  Debugging complexity increases exponentially with the number of bugs.

Answer (score 0):

You will be encountering compilation error.
No need of multiple end if ;

Correct queries:

```
    DECLARE


    CURSOR EMP_UPDATE IS
        SELECT EMP_ID ,NAME ,DESIGNATION ,SALARY ,GRADE  
        FROM EMPLOYEE1 for update ;


    BEGIN 
            FOR REC IN EMP_UPDATE LOOP
                IF REC.EMP_ID <= MAX(REC.EMP_ID)  and  REC.NAME IS NOT NULL and REC.SALARY <= 1000 
                THEN
                UPDATE EMPLOYEE1 SET GRADE = 'D' WHERE EMP_ID = REC.EMP_ID;
                ELSE IF REC.SALARY BETWEEN 1001 AND 5000 THEN
                UPDATE EMPLOYEE1 SET GRADE = 'C' WHERE EMP_ID = REC.EMP_ID;
                ELSE IF REC.SALARY BETWEEN 5001 AND 10000 THEN
                UPDATE EMPLOYEE1 SET GRADE = 'B' WHERE EMP_ID = REC.EMP_ID;
                ELSE IF REC.SALARY BETWEEN 10000 AND 20000 THEN
                UPDATE EMPLOYEE1 SET GRADE = 'A' WHERE EMP_ID = REC.EMP_ID;
                ELSE IF REC.SALARY > 20000 THEN
                UPDATE EMPLOYEE1 SET GRADE = 'S' WHERE EMP_ID = REC.EMP_ID;
                ELSE  
                UPDATE EMPLOYEE1 SET REC.NAME = (SELECT NAME FROM EMPL_DATABASE ED WHERE         ED.EMP_ID = REC.EMP_ID) WHERE EMP_ID = REC.EMP_ID;
                END IF;

            END LOOP;
    END;
```